# Controls added dynamically don't display on my form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I´m adding controls dynamically onto my form, but I can't see those new controls.

My code is:

```
frmFormulario myform = new frmFormulario();

for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++)
{
   String nm = elements[i].name;
   String chk = "chk"+nm;
   CheckBox checkboxWS = new CheckBox();
   checkboxWS.Name = chk;
   checkboxWS.Checked = true;
   checkboxWS.Visible = true;

   checkboxWS.Width.Equals(40);


   myform.Controls.Add(checkboxWS);
   myform.Controls.SetChildIndex(checkboxWS, 0);
}
```

Can anybody spot the problem?

Thanks

My environment is C# Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Windows forms? Web forms? Wpf? Silverlight?

Comment: You're creating a new `frmFormulario` instance each iteration of the loop - is this what you mean to do?

Comment: Thanks Nick I´m gonna change it!

Comment: Besides all the comments and answers. About your frmFormulario class, you can create as many as you want, but without a call to Show or ShowDialog you will never see any of it.

Comment: JMG you should not have changed the problem after you got the answer, it defeats the purpose from historic perspective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
myform.Show();  //or myform.ShowDialog;
```

after the for loop. If you want to completely work on this new window (myform) and discard the former or parent then try creating it in a new thread.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new form inside of the loop as well as the controls.  Once the loop is done it falls out of scope. I'm sure you didn't want to do that, rather add them to an existing form.

Comment: Thanks orn!! Yes I´m trying to add to an existing form

Answer (score 0):

Where do you show myform, the instance of frmFormulario?
Currently you are creating a new form and you don't display it.

Comment: Is this a comment or an answer? Looks more like the former. Ask for clarification in comments.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram: ...and the accepted "answer" is so much different from my "comment"? My "comment" was intended as an answer to get the OP on the right track... Sure... I too can write myform.Show();... (hey... I just did)... The problem isn't the answer... the problem is the question... I'll let you think about that one... ;)